# How to change a model property when a client clicks on an image on MVC 4 VS 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am writing a Facebook application with MVC4 on VS 2012.
I am trying to call a c# method after the client clicks on an image.

All I could until now is to call a JavaScript function "onclick" but it not very helpful because I need to change my model's state and for this I need to call a C# method on a click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the URL Helpers like below to invoke a Method inside a controller.

```
<img src="myImage" onclick="location.href ='@Url.Action("ImageAction","Home")'"/>
```

Where `ImageAction` is the action method and `Home` is the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specifics of the Facebook application, but you can try to use jQuery .load() method in your JavaScript function to send the request to the server and process the result. See [jQuery .load() method](http://api.jquery.com/load/)